# Cannot open webpage from flash button

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-2, flash-cs6

I want to open a webpage from a flash button. I'm using adobe flash CS6, action script2.

Below is the code i have tried:

```
on (release, releaseOutside ) {
    getURL("http://www.google.com", "_self");
}
```

It works fine when i test it in (Test Movie -> in flash Professional).
But it doesn't work when i test using (Test Movie -> in Browser) and also doesn't work after exporting it.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to security measures. Change '_self' to '_blank' within your AS or set 'allowScriptAccess' to 'always' within your html. Refer to [this page](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/links-swf-files-dont-function.html) for more info.